# Get Elements from one array based on list of index from another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2 numpy array something like this

```
a = [array([ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1]), array([ 0.2,  0.2,  0.2])]

b = [0 0 0 1]
```

What I want is something like this --

```
c = [[0.1,  0.1,  0.1],[0.1,  0.1,  0.1],[0.1,  0.1,  0.1],[0.2, 0.2, 0.2]]
```

i.e. elements of a based on index of b.

Is there a way I can achieve this using numpy and vectorization i.e. without looping over the values?

Answer (score 1):

If you store `a` as a two-dimensional numpy array:

```
>>> a = np.array([[0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.2, 0.2, 0.2]])
# result: array([[ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1],
#                [ 0.2,  0.2,  0.2]])
```

or even convert `a` to a numpy array via `a = np.array(a)`,
then you can use the list b to access the elements as desired:

```
>>> b = [0,0,0,1]
>>> print(a[b])
array([[ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1],
       [ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1],
       [ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1],
       [ 0.2,  0.2,  0.2]])
```

and if you need a `list` as output then use `tolist()` method of the `numpy` arrays:

```
>>> (np.asarray(a)[b]).tolist()
[[0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.2, 0.2, 0.2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension

```
[a[x].tolist() for x in b]
```

Comment: can you please expand a bit on this answer to help explain how this resolves the question so the asker can understand better for themselves for next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy

a = [numpy.array([ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1]), numpy.array([ 0.2,  0.2,  0.2])]
b = [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

---

**Alternative 1**:

```
print([a[x].tolist() for x in b])
```

Output:

```
[[0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.2, 0.2, 0.2]]
```

---

**Alternative 2**:

```
print(numpy.array(a)[b])
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.1  0.1  0.1]
 [ 0.1  0.1  0.1]
 [ 0.1  0.1  0.1]
 [ 0.2  0.2  0.2]]
```

---

**Alternative 3**:

```
print(list(map(lambda i: a[i], b)))
```

Output:

```
[array([ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1]), array([ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1]), array([ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1]), array([ 0.2,  0.2,  0.2])]
```

---

**Alternative 4**:

```
from operator import itemgetter
print(list(itemgetter(*b)(a)))
```

Output:

```
[array([ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1]), array([ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1]), array([ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1]), array([ 0.2,  0.2,  0.2])]
```

Comment: a[b] will not work since "a" is a list in your case.

Comment: you are right, I appreciate your help. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Using numpy

If you want using numpy then:

```
print([a[i].tolist() for i in b])
```

> Without using numpy :

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.2, 0.2, 0.2]])
b = [0,0,0,1]

print([value_1.tolist() for value in b for index,value_1 in enumerate(a) if index==value])
```

above list comprehension is same as :

```
final=[]
for value in b:
    for index,value_1 in enumerate(a):
        if index==value:
            final.append(value_1.tolist())

print(final)
```

output:

```
[[0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.2, 0.2, 0.2]]
```